# Software para criar documentação sem usar o código-fonte

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, documentação

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma API, bem  grandinha, e quero criar a documentação, mas, a maioria dos programas que achei apenas pegam a documentação a partir dos comentários do código-fonte, o que eu quero fazer mesmo é escrever manualmente tudo que a API deve ter e formatar em documentação **antes** de criar o código, e ir construindo baseando na documentação, como uma espécie de UML.

Pode parecer meio doido, mas isso ajuda muito. Os programas de UML são muito ruins, é horrível ter que representar graficamente (quadrados e setas pra todo lado), eu me perco de tão grande que fica.

Estou a procura de algo bem simples, apenas um lugar onde tenha campos para classes, variáveis, métodos, enums etc, só pra digitar mesmo texto e criar as páginas em HTML ou PDF.

Comment: Cite um programa que gera documentação. Eu conheço programas que formatam documentação. A não ser que esteja falando de algo muito trivial que não sirva pra muita coisa. De qualquer forma, a documentação não olha o algoritmo, só o contrato. Se não quer fazer o UML (concordo com você) escreva os contratos, descreva a API em código mesmo e manda o "documentador" gerar o texto. Depois você implementa os comportamentos e os detalhes de implementação que independem da API.Na verdade isto é o que todo mundo deveria fazer na maioria das situações.Dê mais informações pra ver se transformo em resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, se eu não achar nada acho mesmo que eu vou ter q encher de métodos vazios, mas o excesso de comentários também prejudicam a leitura do código, infelismente

Answer (score 4):

> Eu estou desenvolvendo uma API

Então qual o problema em definir a API usando classes e interfaces e documentar o que cada método deve fazer?

Exemplo:

```
/**
 * Esta classe deve implementar comportamentos comuns a todos os animais
 */
abstract class Animal {
    /**
     * Consome uma implementação de {@link Comida}.
     * @param comida O animal pode rejeitar a comida se não for do tipo que ele gosta
     * @throws AnimalNaoPodeComerIssoException
     */
    abstract void comer(Comida comida);
}

/**
 * Interface implementada por animais que voam.
 */
interface Voador {
    /**
     * Desloca o animal até o local especificado.
     * @param local Onde o animal deve pousar
     */
    void voar(Local local);
}


/**
 * Detalhes sobre como implementar um Pombo...
 */
class Pombo extends Animal implements Voador { 
    //detalhes sobre como implementar os comportamentos específicos
}
```

Enfim, tudo vai para o Javadoc, aí basta o programador seguir o que está ali.

> o que eu quero fazer mesmo é escrever manualmente tudo que a API deve ter e formatar em documentação antes de criar o código

Use Word ou qualquer editor de texto. Talvez uma ferramenta colaborativa como Confluence (nota: eu trabalho para a Atlassian) seja melhor por facilitar o trabalho de várias pessoas e versionamento do documento.

Diagramas UML específicos podem ser adicionados onde você precisar.

> um lugar onde tenha campos para classes, variáveis, métodos, enums etc,

Crie uma tabela como modelo. Não precisa de uma ferramenta para isso, basta ter um mínimo de disciplina para documentar.

> Os programas de UML são muito ruins, é horrível ter que representar graficamente (quadrados e setas pra todo lado)

Eu concordo que a maioria é horrível. O melhor que eu conheço é o Enterprise Architect, que usei algumas vezes para criar documentos de arquitetura de novos sistemas que iam ser desenvolvidos.

Entretanto, dizer que fica confuso por causa do programa não é verdade. Provavelmente você precisa se familiarizar melhor com UML e com a ferramenta.

Com UML porque você não precisa representar 100% do programa em diagramas, apenas os conceitos mais importantes.

Com a ferramenta porque você pode distribuir os objetos em diferentes diagramas para cada caso de uso. Tentar modelar tudo em um diagrama gigante não é boa prática.

Comment: É, estou fazendo desse modo mesmo, mas o grande problema de "usando classes e interfaces e documentar o que cada método deve fazer", é que meu código tem tanto comentário que os métodos parecem que desapareceram, então prefiro deixar o código limpo e me guiar por uma documentação no 2º monitor. (Este programa de uml e bom mesmo!)

Answer (score 1):

Há no Eclipse (não sei se é o IDE que usa) algo que permite montar as classes com seus membros por uma formulário básico e ele gerar o código. Isto pode simplificar um pouco a confecção do código, eventualmente pode até gerar alguns comentários que já ajudem na documentação.

[image: Java Create Class Wizard]

É possível que exista algum *plugin* que vai além disto e facilite um pouco mais, mas não espere muito. Já vi alguma coisa para outros IDEs/linguagens, mas deve existir alguma coisa para Java.

Eu concordo que fazer todo o UML nem sempre é desejável, mas pode ser uma solução razoável se quiser apenas que gere os contratos sem maiores implicações. Não precisa fazer tudo perfeitinho, indicar as relações, etc.

Mesmo que não tenha a solução é escrever os contratos públicos da API. Algo que é útil independente de ser usado para criar documentação.

Estes softwares documentadores não conseguem documentar de fato, eles apenas pegam informações disponíveis no código para gerar um texto em um formato específico. Eles conseguem fazer alguma coisa com os contratos definidos (classes, interfaces, métodos, etc.). Tudo o que é público seria documentado. Em tese é possível fazer com as partes privadas também, mas não costuma ser adequado porque é detalhe de implementação e não faz parte da API.

Para ter informações mais relevantes terá que escrever comentários documentadores. Será algo quase totalmente manual. A automação será mínima.

Comment: Ainda assim não me ajuda. Realmente, será que eu mesmo vou ter que fazer um programa? Eu nunca imaginaria que seria tão difícil encontrar algo tão simples.